# С# MongoDB, как передать картинку в MongoDB и вытащить потом оттуда

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
Нужно передать картинку в поле "photo" в MongoDB, далее ее надо как-то извлечь и прочитать.
```

Может как то преобразовать картинку в массив байтов и передать в таком виде в MongoDB, далее извлечь через GetValue и конвертировать в изображение. Но, елси делать таким способом, то я не знаю как извлечь через foreach в виде массива байтов.

```
BsonDocument account = new BsonDocument {
                     {"_id",$"{textbox1.Text}"},
                     {"password", $"{textbox2.Text}"},
                     {"E-mail", $"{textbox3.Text}"},
                     {"name", $"{textbox4.Text}"},
                     {"age", Convert.ToInt32(age.Value)},
                     {"photo", //сюда вставить картинку//},
                    };
```

Comment: Получите массив байт и конвертируйте в строку Base64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось вот так:

```
    byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes("путь к файлу");
// например byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\noavatar.png");
                        BsonDocument account = new BsonDocument {
                         {"_id",$"{textbox1.Text}"},
                         {"password", $"{textbox2.Text}"},
                         {"E-mail", $"{textbox3.Text}"},
                         {"name", $"{textbox4.Text}"},
                         {"age", Convert.ToInt32(age.Value)},
                         {"photo", array},//в поле photo я отправляю массив байтов картинки
                        };      
        collection.InsertOne(account); //отправляем в базу данных
```

Далее принимаем.

```
 foreach (var doc in acc)
            {              
                 bs = doc.GetValue("photo");
            }

photoimg = bs.AsByteArray;//конвертируем из BsonValue в массив байтов
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photoimg, 0, photoimg.Length);
profileimage.Image = new Bitmap(ms);// тут я присваиваю картинку пиктурбоксу
```

Как то так.